# jquery datepicker - calculate date difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new at this and I really need your help because I've been struggling for days with this…
I want to calculate days between two dates chosen with datepicker. Am I on the right track with this or am I doing this completely wrong? All I know is that when I click on Number of days, it doesn't show anything. Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: "01/07/2012", maxDate: "01/30/2012" });

            $("#datepicker1").datepicker({ beforeShow: setminDate });

            var start1 = $('#datepicker');      
            function setminDate() {          
                var p = start1.datepicker('getDate');          
                if (p) { 
                    var k ="01/30/2012";            
                    return {
                    minDate: p,
                    maxDate:k
                }};         
            }           
            function clearEndDate(dateText, inst) {          
                end1.val('');      
            }  
        });
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
    });
    $('button').click(function() {
        var start = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
        var end   = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
        var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
        alert(days);
    });
    </script>
    <body>
    <form>
        from: 
        <input id="datepicker" readonly='true'/><br>
        to: 
        <input id="datepicker1" readonly='true'/><br>
    </form>
        <br><button>number of days</button>

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: first correct the order of script inclusion on the page first of all `jquery.js` should be included then the other js files/lib using the jquery

Comment: are start and end getting values?  are they dates or ints?  any exceptions anywhere?

Answer (score 12):

working for me after making this change

```
    var start = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var end   = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
    var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
    alert(days);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/diode/L2et3/3/

Comment: I can see on your link that this is working for you, but when I copy exactly the same to my document, it doesn't. Should I change the part beetween <head> and  $(document).ready(function ()?

Comment: I see this warning event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future

Comment: I had to use Math.round(days) to get a whole number of days