# JS HTML conditions if else or switch

Tags: javascript, html

hello I saw the post and I built this code ... but it does not work ...
I have a radio and a difference between dates
I want to make is that "if the radio number 1 is checked and if the days are between 0 and 1, the price written in the variable is = 40", "if the radio number 1 is checked and if the days are between 2 and 3 the price written in the variable is = 37 "and so on.
I tried using if else and switch but it does not work tell me you know something?
this is the working example without changing the price according to the days http://www.motoeshopping.com/noleggio.php
THANKS

HTML

```
<form action="prenotaa.php" name="modpren" id="modpren" method="post">
<br/>
  <label for="from">Dal</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from"  onChange="startEndDate(); calcolo();"> 
  al
  <label for="to"></label>
  <input type="text" id="to" name="to" onChange="startEndDate(); calcolo();">
<br/><br/>

Seleziona i veicoli di cui richiedere la disponibilità<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="46" onClick="calcolo();" id="v1"/>
    FIAT GRANDE PUNTO 1.3 DIESEL <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="55" onClick="calcolo();" id="v2"/>
   PEUGEOT 208 1.4 DIESEL  <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="36" onClick="calcolo();" id="v3"/>
   FIAT PANDA 1.2 BENZINA <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="55" onClick="calcolo();" id="v4"/>
   FIAT SEDICI 1.9 DIESEL  <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="40" onClick="calcolo();" id="v5"/>
   HYUNDAI I 10 1.1 BENZINA<br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="38" onClick="calcolo();" id="v6"/>
   TOYOTA AYGO 1.0 BENZINA  <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="38" onClick="calcolo();" id="v7"/>
   NISSAN MICRA 1.2 BENZINA <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="55" onClick="calcolo();" id="v8"/>
   MULTIPLA 1.9 DIESEL   <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="36" onClick="calcolo();" id="v9"/>
   SCOOTER APRILIA ATLANTIC - 125 <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="36" onClick="calcolo();" id="v10"/>
   SCOOTER SUZUKI UH 125 <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="75" onClick="calcolo();" id="v11"/>
   HONDA TRANSALP 650 <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="95" onClick="calcolo();" id="v12"/>
   PULLMINO 9 POSTI FORD TRANSIT 2.2 DIESEL <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="95" onClick="calcolo();" id="v13"/>
   PULMINO 9 POSTI NISSAN PRIMASTAR 2.5 DIESEL<br/>
   <input type="radio" name="veicoli" value="95" onClick="calcolo();" id="v14"/>
   FURGONE TRASPORTO MERCI - DUCATO MAXI 2.3 DIESEL<br/><br/>

   <input type="radio" name="km" value="10" id="km_0" onClick="calcolo();">
 Km Illimitati 
 <input type="radio" name="km" value="0" id="km_1" onClick="calcolo();">
 100km inclusi</p>

 <br/>Servizi aggiuntivi<br/>


<input type="checkbox" name="ass[]" value="Furto-Incendio" >
Assicurazione Furto/Incendio 
<input type="checkbox" name="ass[]" value="Casco" >
Casco

<br/><br/>

Calcolo preventivo <br/>
Giorni<input type="number" name="giorni" id="giorni" value=""  > &nbsp;

Veicolo €<input type="number" name="checkveicoli" id="checkveicoli" value=""  required readonly>&nbsp;

Km €<input type="number" name="checkkm" id="checkkm" value=""  required readonly><br/><br/>
Totale: €<input type="number" name="totalesomma" id="totalesomma" value="" class="number1" readonly ><br/><br/>

Nome e Cognome
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome">
Numero di Tel.
<input type="text" id="tel" name="tel"></p><br/>e-mail
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>

<input type="submit" value="Invia">
</form>
```

METHOD 1 if else

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (veicoli[v1].checked==true && document.modpren.giorni.value >=0 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=1) { document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=40; }

else if (veicoli[v1].checked==true && document.modpren.giorni.value >=2 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=3) {document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=37;}

else if (veicoli[v1].checked==true && document.modpren.giorni.value >=4 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=6){document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=35;}

else if (veicoli[v1].checked==true && document.modpren.giorni.value >=7 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=14){document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=33;}

else if (veicoli[v1].checked==true && document.modpren.giorni.value >=15 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=29){document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=30;}

else if(veicoli[v1].checked==true && document.modpren.giorni.value >=30){document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=27;}

else {modpren.checkveicoli.value=50;}

</script>
```

METHOD 2 switch

```
switch (veicoliparz=40){
    case (document.modpren.giorni.value >=0 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=1):
    document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=40;
    break;

    case (document.modpren.giorni.value >=2 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=3):
    document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=37;
    break;

    case (document.modpren.giorni.value >=4 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=6):
    document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=35;
    break;

    case (document.modpren.giorni.value >=7 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=14):
    document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=33;
    break;

    case (document.modpren.giorni.value >=15 && document.modpren.giorni.value <=29):
    document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=30;
    break;

    case (document.modpren.giorni.value >=30):
    document.modpren.checkveicoli.value=27;
    break;
    }
```

Comment: The switch statement doesn't make sense. None of the cases will resolve to `40`. Is this a typo?

Comment: hello thanks for the reply ... it was a test. it is just that the studio js

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly addressing your input fields.

The correct way to retrieve an input element (without jQuery) is to use document.getElementById:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

so instead of `document.modpren.giorni.value` you should say: `document.getElementById("giorni")`;

Here is a fiddle for you that shows how you should be retrieving your values:
http://jsfiddle.net/q066gkk5/

I have also added an onchange handler for the "giorni" select box so that your total properly updates.
Please note that you should not be attaching event handlers on the html tags - but rather thru JS - you can read about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: hello first of all thank you very much! I did as you say but it takes the input value 40 more ... it is as if the law does not change the days and accordingly ... I HAVE UPDATED YOUR LINK ON DECK jsfiddle.net/q066gkk5/1

Comment: Ok - I think you really need to take a step back. You now have added Jquery to your code (using the $) but you didn't include the sources - so that won't work. Also, if you use jQuery then you can get the values of your fields by using $("#idOfTheFieldgoesHere").val() - In your fiddle I notice console errors right away - you also haven't changed any of the other fields on how you get the value - remember you have to use document.getElementById or the jquery way $("#...") ... Also - to use the jqueryUI datepicker you need to make sure you include the necessary jqueryUi files

Comment: I've had it on and I have not copied
I updated the link

Comment: Ok - take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/q066gkk5/11/ it should help you get further (note: in JS fiddle you have to add your css and js files under "resources" on the left to make sure  they get loaded.
I am not really sure what you're trying to to - so I added some comments to areas that are unclear. Make sure you check your code in the developer console (in Chrome) or Firebug (on Firefox)

Comment: Birgit Martinelle sorry I did the other vehicles but it only works v8 "multipla". I tried to create 8 different functions and call them individually but it does not work the same

I have answered your question by commenting
http://jsfiddle.net/q066gkk5/13/

Comment: the date the decimal places for me to do truncate the number $ ("# days"). val (pareseInt ((todate - fromdate) / 86400000)); does not work. What can I use?

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901649/jquery-datepicker-calculate-date-difference

Comment: this is for the date ... for the fact that I only work an if? what could be the problem?

Comment: so your if/else blocks have to be re-structured - http://jsfiddle.net/q066gkk5/15/
I changed some logic around to keep the code a little cleaner. I think it should be quite clear what I am doing -this should get you going

Comment: thanks so much!!! you have been very kind and amenable. I'm sorry if I gave you too much bother but I'm starting out with javascript =) thanks again

Comment: Oh no worries - it reminds me of me when I first started learning how to program. It all falls into place one day ;)
If you could "accept" this as the answer that would be cool. Thanks!